# Make a button/class change it's own color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm. I just began learning HTML and CSS. My question is: How do I make the buttons above change color once they're clicked:

```
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search" onclick="myFunction()"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
</div>
```

I've tried adding an onclick event, but it didn't work.
This is the function:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("fa fa-search").style.color = "red";
}
</script>
```

The full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0}

.icon-bar {
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 0.2%;
    width: 90px;
    background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.85);;
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 255, 0.5);
}

.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 255, 1);
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search" onclick="myFunction()"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
</div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("fa fa-search").style.color = "red";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you read closely: `getElementById` - But you don't have such ID element

Comment: [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) looks for an ID you are searching for classes. Either use [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: getElementById("fa fa-search") not the id in html

Comment: You are trying to select an element using getElementById(). If you want to use this you will have to add an 'id' to that element. e.g. <a id="fa">

Comment: You can use => `document.querySelector(".fa-search").style.color = "red";`

Comment: How do I not have that element? It's because it's a class? @RokoC.Buljan

Comment: Btw, notice that `on_something=...` event handler accepts _arbitrary_ Javascript code, not necessary a function call, so this one-liner will be a perfectly valid : `<button type="button" onclick="this.style.color='red';">My Lovely Button</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't use inline JavaScript `on*=""` handlers, same as you hopefully don't use inline `style=""` attributes. JavaScript should be in one place only and that's your script tag or file.
- Use [`Element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- Use [`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get your desired elements
- Use [`NodeList.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) to loop your elements
- Use [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) with the API methods `.add()` `.remove()` etc.
- Use higher specificity in your CSS by doing `.icon-bar a.active` to override the `:hover` styles.

```js
const ELS_barItems = document.querySelectorAll(".icon-bar a");

function makeActive(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault(); // prevent browser action on Anchors
  ELS_barItems.forEach(el => el.classList.remove("active"));
  ev.currentTarget.classList.add("active");
}

ELS_barItems.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", makeActive));
```

```css
body {margin:0}

.icon-bar {
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 0.2%;
    width: 90px;
    background-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.85);;
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 255, 0.5);
}

.icon-bar a.active {
  background-color: rgba(0, 140, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="icon-bar">
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand where am I supposed to add that conts. In a .js file? And for what I understood, it turns one class active and disables other if it's already active, right?

Comment: @HugoAlmeida exactly. Removes the class from all, adds to one only.

Comment: @HugoAlmeida place all the JS inside a `<script></script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag. Or create a `scripts.js` and use like `<script src="scripts.js"></script>`, again, before the closing body tag.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I wanted. Also, how can I made the active override hover? I've put it higher then my hover in all my ingenuity, but that didn't work, lol
This is my CSS:
https://pastebin.pl/view/44ce4e1c

Comment: @HugoAlmeida you can see in my answer how I overrided the `:hover`...

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the element reference to your function:

```html
<button onclick="turnRed(this)">click</button>
```

and your Javascript:

```Js
turnRed = function(e){
  e.style.background = 'red'
}
```

As for your code, the problem is that you are calling `getElementById("fa fa-search")` but you're passing a class instead. You could change to `getElementsByClassName` but remember that every element with that class would change as well.

Comment: `on*=""` handlers are hard to debug. JS should be in one place only, not dispersed around your HTML file. Also (in that specific case) CSS should be best used for styling, not JS.